# Why can't I search for strings in wireshark after visiting plain website while capturing packets?

Tags: networking, wireshark

I'm trying to understand how the whole thing works and I don't understand why I can't search for a string in wireshark when I visit a non-encrypted website while capturing packets for that website IP. Can't find a single word that appear on the browser. Any idea how this works ?

Answer (score 0):

By default you are looking at the binary (hex) representation of the payload data in the packets, which for the case of plain text web traffic would be [ascii encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

Wireshark does support representing the binary data as ascii symbols instead of binary - this is a [write up detailing](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvFollowTCPSection.html) how to do that.

Here's an excerpt from the section on HTTP and ASCII viewing in that link:

> If you are working with TCP based protocols it can be very helpful to
>   see the data from a TCP stream in the way that the application layer
>   sees it. Perhaps you are looking for passwords in a Telnet stream, or
>   you are trying to make sense of a data stream. Maybe you just need a
>   display filter to show only the packets of that TCP stream. If so,
>   Wireshark’s ability to follow a TCP stream will be useful to you

**...**

> The stream content is displayed in the same sequence as it appeared on
>   the network. Traffic from A to B is marked in red, while traffic from
>   B to A is marked in blue. If you like, you can change these colors in
>   the “Colors” page if the “Preferences” dialog.
>
> Non-printable characters will be replaced by dots.
>
> The stream content won’t be updated while doing a live capture. To get
>   the latest content you’ll have to reopen the dialog.
>
> You can choose from the following actions:
>
> Save As: Save the stream data in the currently selected format. 
> Print:
>   Print the stream data in the currently selected format.
>  Direction:
>   Choose the stream direction to be displayed (“Entire conversation”,
>   “data from A to B only” or “data from B to A only”).
>  Filter out this
>   stream: Apply a display filter removing the current TCP stream data
>   from the display.
>  Close: Close this dialog box, leaving the current
>   display filter in effect. 
> You can choose to view the data in one of
>   the following formats:
>
> ASCII: In this view you see the data from each direction in ASCII.
>   Obviously best for ASCII based protocols, e.g. HTTP.
>  EBCDIC: **...**